# How to implement OWL relationships in RDF triples using Java?

Tags: java, database, rdf, owl

I have two columns of entities (Subjects), and I would like to specify the relationship between them like this:

```
<subject_1>  <relationship> <subject_2>
```

What I really want to do is to add a relationship between the words. For example, if I have two words like "`CAR`" and "`VEHICLE`". After running the program, it has to generate a `semantic relationship` between them such as:

```
<car> <is_a> <vehicle>
```

Now, "is_a" is a relation defined semantically between words. How and where can I find and get all these relations, such as "is_a", "part_of" and so on, so that I can use them in my program. 
(I want to reach a database or API where all these relations where defined so that I can run two words to get the relation between them.)

The problem is I know that Wikipedia and WordNet APIs defines more than 50000 relations between subjects. I looked all over the internet to reach to these relations so that I can implement them, but I did not find any. Does any one have an idea about how can I reach these relations or how can I implement them using Java?

A link to to Github repository, or a link to their database will be so appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're after: what do you mean when you say you want to 'reach these relations so that you can implement them'? Can you show an actual example of the entities that you have and the relations that you'd like to add between them?

Comment: "OWL defines more than 50000 relations between subjects" - ehm, what? OWL defines nothing. OWL is a modeling language. It's up to you to define the relationships aka object properties in your ontology. And it's up to you to decide on whether to reuse existing public ontologies which itself indeed define some relationships for their domain of interest. Last point, there is no central repository for all ontologies that are publicly available. But as Jeen said, it remains unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Thanks for your answer, I updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @AKSW I want to reuse the public existing ontologies to define the relationships between the words. But I did not find any database or Github repository to reuse them. So how can I reuse that ontologies ?

Comment: There is no central repository. Why do you think so? Everybody can make his/her own ontologies and nobody has to publish them. You can try to search for ontologies that cover a domain that you're interested in, but you can also define the relationships in your ontology by yourself.

Comment: @AKSW I think you are right about creating my own ontology but I don't think that I have to create everything from the scratch because if you run any word on any API or any dictionary, you will get all the related words and the relationship between them. That means there are already many ontologies were made. My question how to use these predefined ontologies like "is_a" or "part_of" which I really do not think I can link all the the words in the dictionary with them.I read about that in W3C and read about OWL. Would you please just provide a link to a predefined ontology that I can reuse ?

Comment: @AKSW I saw something like this: https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/Relations 
But how can I link these relations to my words. For example if I run to words, I want the output is the semantic relationship between them. THANKS!!!!

Comment: you're mixing up different things here I guess. If you create an ontology, you can either define your own classes and relationsships or you can reuse existing ones by importing them (in OWL this is possible) or simply reuse the URI of the relation (usually done in simple RDF). Nothing more, nothing less

Comment: And your link is just a textual description but not an RDF dataset or OWL ontology.

Comment: @AKSW I really appreciate that, it is a lot of help. Apologize for mixing the stuff, but I think you reached what I really want. I searched for what you said, and I saw this URI for the relation childOf:  http://purl.org/vocab/relationship/childOf
If could please tell me how to reuse this and it will be greatly appreciated. Please write your answer as an answer to the question so that I can rate it up. THANKSSS!!!

Comment: In the simplest case, reuse it simply means to use the URI in your ontology. That's all. If you also want to reuse additional information about the relation (if exists), then in OWL you can add the ontology URL as an import.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single, central spot that defines *all* relations, though there are initiatives for specialized search (like [Swoogle](http://swoogle.umbc.edu/)) or open data portals (like [CKAN](https://ckan.org/)) that can be helpful to find vocabularies.

For basic data modelling relations like `is-a`, `part-of`, etc., there are the RDFS, OWL, and SKOS vocabularies. They have websites with documentation and of course they are themselves published as RDF/OWL, so if you need them to be accessible from a database, you could easily just load them into your own triplestore and query them.

For other kinds of relations there are other, domain-specific ontologies. If you want to reuse them you'll have to look them up individually. How this typically works in practice is that you have a domain in mind, and then you go and search for a matching vocabulary: "I want to model relations having to do with books - so I want to look for a books ontology, or perhaps a library ontology".